# Logon wallpaper differs from user wallpaper

Tags: desktop-background

Since I changed my wallpaper, I noticed that the logon screen didn't update. It still uses the wallpaper before I updated it. This is in Ubuntu 13.04.

Anywone any suggestions? I have been playing around with ccsm and unity tweak tool, so maybe I did something wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an encrypted home directory where your wallpaper is located? If so try to make a new directory e.g /wallpaper, copy your wallpaper there and set it from there.
This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled the compiz wallpaper plugin in ccsm and told the file manager not to handle the desktop, then this could be the reason for the different wallpapers.